# Django app keeps logging out for standard user and admin (staff) - cookies issue

Tags: python, django, cookies

Have a working Django app in production, there are several issues that appear while logging in, moving to sites that are for staff only (using decorators), etc.

- When logging in, I sometimes need to do it 2x, 3x times, or more, just
  repeat the username & password, so the user can get inside the portal (no error is thrown)
- When logging in as "staff", have some sites on the Portal which are restricted, often it asks to enter the password again (and shows the standard Django admin login page although still working on the app) - like the web browser does not remember that "staff" logged in already
- When already re-logged as the staff (above point), while continuing to do some actions on the page, like adding posts when hitting the "post" button it asks for the password again (note, I created an admin page on the website, to add posts, manage users, etc.)

I suspect this is related to either:

- My Cookie setup
- Decorators used, restricting access to logged-in users or staff only

Appreciate your help!

**settings.py**

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 24*60*60*7 #1 week
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'www.mywebsite.com'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 86400  # 1 day
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY") #from .env file
```

Example where staff can only access, with decoratror ***views.py***

```
@staff_member_required
@login_required
def newsletter(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    # end the rest of the code
```

I also used earlier the below, but didn't make any difference:

```
@staff_member_required(login_url='home')
```

Here is the ***decorators.py*** that I recently added, but not sure if this is OK or just a generic one - not sure if this is needed at all. Should I add this to the decorators.py or remove it and use the default @staff_member_required as it is:

```
def staff_member_required(view_func=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
                          login_url='admin:login'):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in and is a staff
    member, redirecting to the login page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_staff,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if view_func:
        return actual_decorator(view_func)
    return actual_decorator
```

Comment: I see you have set `SESSION_ENGINE`  to use caches, what is the value for `SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS`? If you haven't set that what is the `CACHES` setting like? You say "moving to sites" do these sites use the same cache?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for the note. Yeah, I'm lost here + a newbie, so I think I got all the settings you see above completely wrong. Don't have other ```CACHES``` settings and not ```SESSION_CACH_ALIAS```. What should be the right settings to avoid such a constant need for re-logging etc.? ("moving to site" ignore it, it's within the same URL, does not move across different wwww)

Comment: Well the default cache is `django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache` which caches in memory. This means you are caching all of your user sessions in memory, when the cached data expires your user is going to get logged out, and this cache is also going to get cleared whenever the server stops, if you have multiple processes of your server running depending on which process your request hits your user might or might not be logged in...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it really helped. Issue fixed. As suggested in the link from you, I followed Memcached setup https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/#memcached. Many thanks!